# Properties not found in OOP

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I got Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /config/mySQL_class.php on line 19 
I have test my code but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem, I'm just a beginner programmer who started to try OOP yesterday. Any Ideas?

```
<?php


class Database
{



    public $data;

    public $mysqli;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

            echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";

        exit;

        }
    }



    public function __destruct(){

        $this->mysqli->close();

    }


    public function read(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` ";
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
    $num_result = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_result>0)
    {

        while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){

            $this->data[]=$rows;

                }
            } else {

                return $this->data;

        }
    }




}

?>
```

Usage

```
include('config/mySQL_class.php');

$obj=new Crud("localhost","root","","crud");
$obj->read();

    <table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <th width="16" scope="row">id</th>
        <td width="95">name</td>
        <td width="140">email</td>
        <td width="104">address</td>
         <td width="71">Mobile</td>
        <td>action</td>
      </tr>

        <?php
        foreach($obj->data as $val){
            extract($val);

            ?>
            <tr>
            <td scope="row"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $address; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mob; ?></td>
             <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">edit</a>|<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: That probably means `mysqli` is not installed in your PHP version? See [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo);

Comment: I can't find mysqli on phpinfo(); @deceze One thing, can I use mysql instead mysqli? thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's a comon error when the MySQLi extension isn't installed on your server.

To check if MySQLi extension is available, try this:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'MySQLi extension is missing!';
} else {
    echo 'MySQLi extension is installed!';
}
```

To install the MySQLi extension, follow [this instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).

It is also possible that you have the MySQLi extension installed, but commented in the php.ini file. Open php.ini and check if extension=php_mysqli.so isn't commented. If so, uncomment and restart apache server.